# Can't load PNG file in HTML

Tags: html, http-status-code-404, png, bootstrap-5

Hello I have a problem with add logo to my website. Firstly I had some example logo

```
<a class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center" href="/">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/cattery/logo-cattery.png" width="250"height="70" class="d-inline-block mr-1 align-bottom" alt=""></a>
</a>
```

And everything was good.
Secondly I bought some logo on logo creator website and now there is a problem with my logo. There is 404 error. I use the same code and localization but another file- the file seems good, I can open it and I can see the content.

My new code:

```
<a class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center" href="/">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/cattery/cattery_logo.png" width="250"height="70" class="d-inline-block mr-1 align-bottom" alt=""></a>
</a>
```

I tried various files from my logo package and I changed localization etc but unfortunatelly I haven't got it.

Answer (score 1):

A 404 error usually indicates that a resource can not be found. Are you completely sure that the path is 100% correct?
Another cause of error could be that (actually both paths) `img/cattery/cattery_logo.png` is a *relative* path, hence the actual path called depends on the currently opened site. Consider changing the path to *absolute*: `/img/...`.